# UK visa application for a person who had overstayed earlier

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, applications, overstaying

About 3 years back my parents, both Indian citizens visited my sister, a UK citizen. About a week before they were supposed to return, my father was hospitalised. The Visa was was about to expire in 2 weeks and my sister  applied for a renewal of visa, citing the reason that

1) my father is not in a position to travel ( backed up by supporting letters of his treating doctors) and

2) my mother needs to be with my father for any assistance.

Subsequently, after close to a months hospitalisation, my father passed away. Visa had expired by then. His funeral also was done in UK.

My mother could not return as her visa renewal application was still under process. His passing away was informed to the visa office and after about 2-3 months, my mother was asked to re apply once more as the original reason did not hold good anymore (since my father was no more). 
  She re apllied and after considerable time (about 15 months from the original application), she was called for a hearing and her application was rejected.

She payed for her ticket and traveled back. I am told that she also got a letter (not sure from whom) which said that as my father's final resting place is in UK, she can visit again. Unfortunately this letter is lost now.

She is planning to travel soon  so that she can be there for his anniversary.

Will she face any hurdles in getting the visa approved due to the overstay? 
  Anything that needs to be done special during the application to indicate her overstay and return?

It will be a visiting visa (6 months)

Comment: What paperwork does your mother have relating to the visa hearing rejection? Does she meet the current eligibility requirements? Just an opinion but I’d say at the least her application is likely to receive extra scrutiny, it would be best to gather all documentation from her earlier visit before applying - for example, and without wishing to sound callous, proof that there are no outstanding NHS health care fees

Comment: Emergency health care is free in the UK for all visitors, so there ought not to be outstanding bills. Since your mother left at her own expense and did not overstay long, I would imagine she has a one year entry ban from the time she left, but even after the ban has expired, her application will still have more scrutiny. I would advise your sister to write to her MP ASAP (this can be done by email) to explain the circumstances and they may write to the home office on her behalf. This could help ensure the compassionate and correct decision is made.

Comment: @MJeffryes A&E services are free to all. Hospital care that isn’t A&E may not be free https://www.nhs.uk/using-the-nhs/nhs-services/visiting-or-moving-to-england/how-to-access-nhs-services-in-england/

Comment: @MJeffryes related question to that - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89497/is-it-true-that-you-can-receive-emergency-care-in-the-uk-completely-free-of-char

Comment: There was a hospital bill and it was settled. There is no outstanding.

Comment: How about applying for a subject access to see what they think about you? Then you can decide how you want to apply.

Comment: @greatone sorry, but what is a subject access?

Comment: It will tell you what information they have on you in their systems. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration